# document.addEventListender test not working using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Example component:

```
class Modal extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onEscPress, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onEscPress, false);
  }

  @bind onEscPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.props.onClose();
    }
  }

  render() {
    <div className=".modal">...</div>
  }
}
```

My test:

```
const closeModal = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<Modal onClose={closeModal} />);

it('executes the `onClose` function when `esc` key is pressed', () => {
  const modal = wrapper.find('.modal');
  modal.simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 27 });
  expect(closeModal).toBeCalled();
});
```

But my test fails because `closeModal()` doesn't get run...

Comment: I've answered something like this before (can't find it now), but the gist is that you mock/stub `document.addEventListener` with your own function that stores each callback in an array (map with shape `eventKey: array(callbacks)`), and when you dispatch the event in your code/test, the mocked/stubbed handler runs through and calls your callback functions.

Comment: @DrewReese awesome thanks. Also, should I be using `mount` instead of `shallow` since that event listener won't get attached if `componentDidMount ` doesn't get run? Or with your process mentioned above I don't have to worry about that?

Comment: I _think_ it matters, but is trivial to test.

Comment: I found where this had come up before for me, it was over in [github](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426#issuecomment-431195329)